# Add frequency counts to 2x2 prop.table

Tags: r, dplyr

How do I add frequency counts to a 2x2 prop.table? So here 'dataset' contains two categorical variables.

```
 dataset %>% prop.table(margin = 2) %>% '*' (100) %>% round(2)
```

I would like the counts in addition to percentages of each category.

Sorry for the dopey example, but it should look like this, except the sum doesn't need to be reported in every cell.

[image]

Comment: Please show a small reproducible example and expected output

Answer (score 0):

A reproducible example and solution:

```
tab <-iris %>% mutate(size = factor(1+(Sepal.Length>median(iris$Sepal.Length)),levels = 1:2, labels = c('S','L'))) %>%
  select(Species, size) %>%
  table()
prop <- prop.table(tab,margin = 2) %>% '*' (100) %>% round(2)

matrix(paste(tab,prop),nrow = nrow(tab),dimnames = dimnames(tab))
```

gives

```
            size
Species      S         L         
  setosa     "50 62.5" "0 0"     
  versicolor "24 30"   "26 37.14"
  virginica  "6 7.5"   "44 62.86"
```

or another solution:

```
iris %>% mutate(size = factor(1+(Sepal.Length>median(iris$Sepal.Length)),levels = 1:2, labels = c('S','L'))) %>%
  group_by(Species, size) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  group_by(size) %>%
  mutate(p = paste(n,round(n/sum(n)*100,2))) %>%
  select(-n) %>%
  spread(size,p,fill = paste(0,0))
```

gives

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  Species    S       L       
  <fct>      <chr>   <chr>   
1 setosa     50 62.5 0 0     
2 versicolor 24 30   26 37.14
3 virginica  6 7.5   44 62.86
```

Answer (score 0):

`addmargins` applied to your table might do what you want.

```
set.seed(34)
n <- 20
tab <- table(sample(1:3, n, replace = TRUE), sample(c("A", "B"), n, replace = TRUE))
addmargins(tab)
```

Comment: addmargins doesn't add percentages to each cell, it only computes functions and adds them to the outer margins.